# newrelic mysql java plugin connection issue

Tags: java, mysql, newrelic

Needed Some help, I installed the `newrelic mysql plugin`, and created a user from script but when I start the agent using `java -jar newrelic_mysql_plugin-1.2.0.jar` it gives me

> com.newrelic.metrics.publish.binding.Context | SEVERE | Unable to
>   obtain a new database connection: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
>   root/PASSWORD_FILTERED, check your MySQL configuration settings.
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

I tried to use it using root credentials for mysql but same error. i can connect from localhost shell using root credentials. and my mysql.instance.json is:

> [ { "name" : "MyApp", "host" : "localhost:3306", "metrics" :
>   "status,newrelic", "user" : "root", "passwd" : "mypassword" }, ]

Reference for Plugin: http://newrelic.com/plugins/new-relic-inc/52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the issue, the default script didn't create the user@'127.0.0.1' just created user@localhost. i created it manually and now its working like charm. just posting the issue hope it will help others.

You can see if user is created or not using

SELECT User FROM mysql.user;

Or to Create a User with limited rights in mysql shell just use.

CREATE USER newrelic@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpass';

GRANT PROCESS,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO newrelic@localhost;

CREATE USER newrelic@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpass';

GRANT PROCESS,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO newrelic@127.0.0.1;

and Define your password in Clean test in mysql json.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't being able to use the plugin on my root user, but with this new newrelic user it worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks! They should change the documentation (CREATE USER newrelic@<INSERT_IP_ADDRESS_HERE>), because in MySQL everyone is thinking of localhost, before 127.0.0.1.